# Indexing items marked as deleted

Tags: sql, postgresql, search, indexing

Due to client requirements I need to implement following scenario:
Whenever user want to delete a record representing a document, that particular record needs to be marked as deleted using simple BOOLEAN `is_deleted` condition.

Document is a general name for one of the tables that store invoices, orders or offers.

Everything is pretty dead simple, but I wonder if there is a way to index records to perform quick searching and somehow skip/omit deleted items (or there is no need to worry about performance at all and use simple where clause `is_deleted=False`).

Other solutions/advices would be appreciated as well.

Comment: You can use partial indexes that omit / include "deleted" records if it really causes performance issues. Otherwise - just let postgres filter them out.

Comment: Postgresql 9.3 has introduced the [Materialized View](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html), this could be of use, but with a boolean field I don't see filtering on that field being much of a performance hit.

Comment: Partial indexes have another benefit other than just making some queries faster, they are also smaller, take up less cache, incur less I/O overhead from maintaining them (there are fewer entries to maintain). Eg. `CREATE INDEX docs_not_deleted_pidx ON docs (some_id) WHERE is_deleted IS FALSE`

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL supports partial indexes.  You can do something like:

```
create index document_id_is_deleted_idx ON document(id) where is_deleted;
```

You can even create unique indexes if you need unique subsets over portions of your data.

Of course getting the right columns in your index is an exercise, but it is quite manageable.

Answer (score 0):

Another option you might like to explore is to move those records to another table, or to use partitioning to separate the deleted and undeleted rows (which would amount to broadly the same thing).

That would let you keep all the records of interest in a smaller table that can be indexed differently from that of the deleted records.

If you went down the partitioning route you'd have a DOCUMENTS master table with DOCUMENTS_DELETED and DOCUMENTS_LIVE tables inheriting from it.